# Python remove outer quotes in a list of lists made from a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame called positive_samples that has a column called Gene Class, which is basically a pair of genes stored as a list. It looks like below

[image]

The entire data frame looks like this.

[image].

So the gene class column is just the other two columns in the data frame combined. I made a list using the gene class column like below. This take all the gene pair lists and make them into a single list.

```
   #convert the column to a list
   postive_gene_pairs = positive_samples["Gene Class"].tolist()
```

This is the output.

[image]

Each pair is now wrapped within double quotes, which I dont want because I loop through this list and use .loc method to locate this pairs in another data frame called new_expression which has them as  an index like this

[image]

```
for positive_gene_pair in positive_gene_pairs:
    print(new_expression_df.loc[[positive_gene_pair],"GSM144819"])
```

This throws a keyerror.

[image]

And it definely because of the extra quotes that each pair is wrapped around because when I instantiate a list like below without quotes it works just fine.

[image]

So my question is how do I remove the extra quotes to make this work with .loc? To make a list just like below, but from a data frame column?.

```
pairs = [['YAL013W','YBR103W'],['YAL011W','YMR263W']]
```

I tried so many workarounds like replace, strip but none of them worked for me as ideally they would work for strings but I was trying to make them work on a list, any easy solution? I just want to have a list of list like this pairs list that does not have extra single or double quotes.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the column to a list? Why not just get a Series out of the dataframe? `positive_gene_pairs = positive_samples[['Gene Class']]`

Comment: I have actually done that already and I still got the same key error, so this is the only workaround I came up that works.

Comment: you showed the code `positive_samples["Gene Class"].tolist()` but the associated output you showed is a numpy array. `tolist()` returns a list (hence its name)- make sure you're overwriting this variable anywhere else in your code.

Comment: If you just need a list you can work with and without apostrophes: `pairs = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(positive_samples['Query Strain ID'], positive_samples['Array Strain ID'])]`

Comment: @pavel thanks, this works, put it as an answer

Comment: @CameronRiddell thanks for the tip, I was actually trying it using a numpy array before I used the tolist()  function that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert list of strings to lists first:

```
import ast

postive_gene_pairs = positive_samples["Gene Class"].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist()
```

And then remove `[]`:

```
for positive_gene_pair in positive_gene_pairs:
    print(new_expression_df.loc[[positive_gene_pair],"GSM144819"])
```

to:

```
for positive_gene_pair in positive_gene_pairs:
    print(new_expression_df.loc[positive_gene_pair,"GSM144819"])
```

Comment: This gets the listed formatted as I want but when I plug it in the loc function, it appends an extra pair of brackets and throws the same key error

Answer (score 0):

define a functio:

```
def listup(initlist):
    # Converting string to list 
    res = ini_list.strip('][').split(', ') 
    
    return res
```

change from

```
postive_gene_pairs = positive_samples["Gene Class"].tolist()
```

to

```
postive_gene_pairs = positive_samples["Gene Class"].apply(listup).tolist()
```

Comment: This now moves the double quotes to be inside as compared to them being on the outside, same key error still persists. 